# Combining Tabs in Excel to next free Column instead of Row

Tags: vba

I have 7 tabs in an excel work book. The information in these tabs are all tables. I need to combine these tables so each one starts in the next empty column. The code that I've tried to make starts on the next empty row, instead of the next empty Column.

Basically, I want all of my headers from each table to all be contained in row 1 instead of starting in the next free row.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim NextEmptyCol As Long
NextEmptyCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column + 1

Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If s.Name <> "Combined" Then
Application.Goto Sheets(s.Name).[A1]
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined"). _
Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Where is the error?

Comment: Instead of beginning the new table in the next free Column, it starts in the next Row. I am trying to keep all of my Headers in row 1

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined").Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)` finds the next free row.  To find the next free column:

```
LastCol = Sheets("Combined").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined"). _
Cells(1, LastCol + 1)
```